# How to temporarily open and close a port to a certain IP on an AWS security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I want to use `aws` cli tool to temporarily open a port to a certain IP address before a backup process starts and close it after it's finished.

I know how to do this through the console, but I couldn't find how to do this programmatically.

Does anyone know what commands I could run to do that?

I was thinking to write a shell script to do that and launch it before the backup, so I found a Circle CI Orb that does exactly the same. However, when I try to launch it using a shell script I get errors. I'm not so good with the shell commands, so maybe somebody could tell me what I could fix below?

The permissions for AWS are set correctly, so I guess I just need to tweak something in the script below.

```
# Get the current IP of the AWS instance the script is launched from

LATEST_IP=$(wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com)

IP="${IP-$LATEST_IP}"

if [[ "${IP}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Could not find your public IP"
    exit 1
fi

# Get the security group ID

GROUPID=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[].[Tags[?Key==`<< parameters.tag-key >>`] | [0].Value, GroupId]' --output table | grep << parameters.tag-value >> | awk '{print $4}') [[ -n "${GROUPID}" ]] || (echo "Could not determine Security Group ID" && exit 0);
                                            
# Adding Rule SSH to Your Security Group

echo Allowing << parameters.description >> to access port $PORT from IP
$IP to the security group $GROUPID

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $GROUPID --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": '<< parameters.port >>', "ToPort": '<< parameters.port >>', "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'$LATEST_IP/<< parameters.mask >>'", "Description": "'<< parameters.description >>'"}]}]' 

# Closing the port
echo "Removing << parameters.description >> access from IP $IP to the security group $GROUPID"


# Delete IP rules matching port

aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $GROUPID --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": '<< parameters.port >>', "ToPort": '<< parameters.port >>', "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp":"'$LATEST_IP/<< parameters.mask >>'", "Description": "'<< parameters.description >>'"}]}]'
```

Comment: "I get errors" - can you clarify what errors exactly?

Comment: It throws an error saying that the `|` is not recognized, so  I think it's about the syntax

Comment: What are `parameters`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Perhaps this is the problem. I guess I need to provide the name of the security group somewhere there and the port that needs to be opened and closed, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **modified** the script so that it **works**. But I don't see much use for it in its current form. It just adds a rule to a SG, and then it removes it immediately after.

I replaced `GROUPID=$(aws ec2 des ...` with just a value of SG ID to use.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Get the current IP of the AWS instance the script is launched from

set -ex

LATEST_IP=$(wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com)

IP="${IP-$LATEST_IP}"

if [[ "${IP}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Could not find your public IP"
    exit 1
fi

echo ${IP}

# Get the security group ID

GROUPID="sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0" # change to your own SG
PORT_FROM=80
PORT_TO=80
MASK_IP="32"
DESCRIPTION="Some-description"
AWS_PROFILE="default" # AWS credentials profile to use

# Adding Rule SSH to Your Security Group

echo Allowing ${GROUPID} to access port $PORT from IP ${IP} to the security group $GROUPID

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $GROUPID \
    --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": '${PORT_FROM}', "ToPort": '${PORT_TO}', "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'$LATEST_IP/${MASK_IP}'", "Description": "'${DESCRIPTION}'"}]}]' \
    --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} 

# Closing the port
echo "Removing ${DESCRIPTION} access from IP $IP to the security group $GROUPID"


# Delete IP rules matching port

aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $GROUPID \
    --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": '${PORT_FROM}', "ToPort": '${PORT_TO}', "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp":"'$LATEST_IP/${MASK_IP}'", "Description": "'${DESCRIPTION}'"}]}]' \
    --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}
```

Example output:

```
++ wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com
+ LATEST_IP=<real-ip-value>
+ IP=<real-ip-value>
+ [[ <real-ip-value> == '' ]]
+ echo <real-ip-value>
<real-ip-value>
+ GROUPID=sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0
+ PORT_FROM=80
+ PORT_TO=80
+ MASK_IP=32
+ DESCRIPTION=Some-description
+ AWS_PROFILE=la
+ echo Allowing sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0 to access port from IP <real-ip-value> to the security group sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0
Allowing sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0 to access port from IP <real-ip-value> to the security group sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0
+ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0 --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 80, "ToPort": 80, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "<real-ip-value>/32", "Description": "Some-description"}]}]' --profile la
+ echo 'Removing Some-description access from IP <real-ip-value> to the security group sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0'
Removing Some-description access from IP <real-ip-value> to the security group sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0
+ aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-0483809ca6b8e91d0 --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 80, "ToPort": 80, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp":"<real-ip-value>/32", "Description": "Some-description"}]}]' --profile la
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marcin I will try it out — but why do you think this is not useful? Isn't it good that a port is temporarily opened and then closed? Do you suggest another solution? Of course, between the opening and the closing I perform certain actions (backup), which I excluded from this script.

Comment: @Aerodynamika Hi. The script just opens it, and then immediately closes it. So the port will be open for few seconds max. Maybe better to split it into two scripts, one which opens, and the second which closes it.